# What are the performance differences with these two uses of the map stream function in java 8

Tags: java, performance, functional-programming

Say I have the functions *mutateElement()* which does *x* operations and *mutateElement2()* which does *y* operations. What is the difference in performance between these two pieces of code.

Piece1:

```
List<Object> = array.stream().map(elem -> 
    mutateElement(elem);
    mutateElement2(elem);
)
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Piece2:

```
List<Object> array = array.stream().map(elem -> 
    mutateElement(elem);
)
.collect(Collectors.toList());

array = array.stream().map(elem -> 
    mutateElement2(elem);
)
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Clearly The first implementation is better as it only uses one iterator, however the second uses two iterators. But would the difference be noticeable if I had say a million elements in the array.

Answer (score 2):

1. The first implementation is not better simply because it uses only one iterator, the first implementation is better because it only collects once.
2. Nobody can tell you whether the difference would be noticeable if you had a million elements.  (And if someone did try to tell you, you should not believe them.)  ***Benchmark it.***

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you use stream or external loop, the problem is the same.
One iteration on the `List` in the first code and two iterations on the `List` in the second code.
The time of execution of the second code is so logically more important.

Besides invoking twice the terminal operation on the stream :

```
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

rather than once, has also a cost.

> But would the difference be noticeable if I had say a million elements
>   in the array.

It could be.
 Now the question is hard to answer : yes or no.
It depends on other parameters such as cpus, number of concurrent users and processing and your  definition of "noticeable".